# Keeping a persistent external monitor configuration between home and office

Tags: display, spaces

I would like to keep the spaces for my two external monitors in the same arrangement between two different environments, home and work. Currently, when I switch between the two, the spaces occupied by my side monitor move over to my main monitor and vice versa. The problem is illustrated below:

[image]

Is there a setting where I can set the monitor numbers so they are persistent between the two settings?

Comment: Are your 4 external monitors all identical, very similar, or nothing like each other [different makes etc]?Same connectors or different, HDMI/TB/DP? I've had struggles like this where it's just become easier to give in & move two of the monitors to where the Mac "prefers" them.

Comment: They are all different monitors. All are connected via hdmi-> displayport adaptors.

Comment: Hmm… OK, so the Mac really ought to be able to 'remember' which goes where. I wonder if it's possible to get it to discard all known data on these displays & start from scratch? That's not something I know how to do, I'm afraid, but maybe someone else on here does. I wish you luck :)